Why isn't dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue key working by using Apache Camel OPC UA Client?
I'm using Apache Camel OPC UA client component to test the data change filter with Deadband Value to acquire the single tag value from Industrial Gateway OPCUA Server.
Current Spring boot and camel-milo component version:
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-milo', version: '3.22.2'
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel.springboot', name: 'camel-spring-boot-starter', version: '4.4.2'

Reading Apache Camel OPC UA client documentation to apply deadband filter feature, if I understood well, I have to use the following properties key:

dataChangeFilterTrigger = StatusValue (I'm using statusValue for checking the value )
dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue = xx (it depends on the deadband that I want to apply on the tag)

My performed tests is telling me that the deadband filter is not working as I showed in the following tests:
Base route with placeholder values replaced on the test id performed :
from("milo-client:opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?
keyStoreUrl=file:C:\\Temp\\application\\certificate\\clientkeystore.jks
&keyPassword=123456
&keyStorePassword=123456
&applicationUri=urn:8409:test:camelopcua
&applicationName=camelopcua&node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_BP)
&dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue=@placeholderTest_x@
&dataChangeFilterTrigger=@placeholderTest_x@
&monitorFilterType=dataChangeFilter")
.log("**** ${body}")
.routeId("routeDeadband");

Test_1)
dataChangeFilterTrigger = StatusValue
dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue = 0.001
2024-07-04 06:36:51,852 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486117072252, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:51 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486117072252, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:51 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:36:52,853 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.9666667}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486126951326, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:52 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486126951326, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:52 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:36:53,849 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.925}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486136802804, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:53 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486136802804, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:53 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:36:54,844 milo-shared-thread-pool-2 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.05}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486146648052, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:54 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486146648052, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:54 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:36:55,854 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.942857}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486156406461, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:55 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486156406461, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:55 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:36:56,849 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.9666667}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486166262211, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:56 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486166262211, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:56 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:36:57,851 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486171756029, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:57 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486171756029, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:57 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:36:58,844 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486187076878, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:58 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486187076878, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:58 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:36:59,849 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486196926821, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:59 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486196926821, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:36:59 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:37:00,851 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486206806697, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:00 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486206806697, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:00 UTC 2024}}2024-07-04 06:37:01,846 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.05}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486216593861, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:01 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486216593861, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:01 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:37:02,847 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486222116969, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:02 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486222116969, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:02 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:37:03,849 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486236275381, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:03 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486236275381, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:03 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:37:04,849 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486247209000, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:04 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486247209000, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:04 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:37:05,853 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486257072613, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:05 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486257072613, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:05 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:37:06,851 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.925}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486266939791, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:06 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486266939791, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:06 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:37:07,848 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486276787705, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:07 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486276787705, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:07 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:37:08,846 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486286565108, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:08 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645486286565108, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:37:08 UTC 2024}}

Test_2)
dataChangeFilterTrigger = StatusValue
dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue = 0.01
2024-07-04 06:34:09,570 milo-shared-thread-pool-2 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.925}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484491791570, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:09 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484491791570, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:09 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:10,573 milo-shared-thread-pool-2 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484501646388, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:10 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484501646388, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:10 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:11,569 milo-shared-thread-pool-2 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.925}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484511409944, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:11 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484511409944, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:11 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:12,568 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484521286485, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:12 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484521286485, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:12 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:13,570 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484531171024, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:13 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484531171024, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:13 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:14,567 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484541032215, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:14 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484541032215, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:14 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:15,566 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484550859004, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:15 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484550859004, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:15 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:16,570 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484561764724, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:16 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484561764724, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:16 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:17,571 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484571580985, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:17 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484571580985, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:17 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:34:18,573 milo-shared-thread-pool-2 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.9666667}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484581482454, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:18 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645484581482454, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:34:18 UTC 2024}}

Test_3)
dataChangeFilterTrigger = StatusValue
dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue = 0.1
 2024-07-04 06:38:56,790 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487367572683, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:38:56 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487367572683, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:38:56 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:38:57,787 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487373034158, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:38:57 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487373034158, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:38:57 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:38:58,785 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487387204906, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:38:58 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487387204906, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:38:58 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:38:59,790 milo-shared-thread-pool-3 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487397079011, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:38:59 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487397079011, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:38:59 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:39:00,789 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487402524037, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:00 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487402524037, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:00 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:39:01,783 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.925}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487412409085, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:01 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487412409085, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:01 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:39:02,785 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.05}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487427749867, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:02 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487427749867, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:02 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:39:03,787 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.05}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487437559370, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:03 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487437559370, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:03 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:39:04,791 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487447390847, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:04 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487447390847, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:04 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:39:05,782 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487457187133, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:05 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487457187133, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:05 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:39:06,789 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.05}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487467051678, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:06 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487467051678, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:06 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:39:07,783 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487472586697, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:07 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645487472586697, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:39:07 UTC 2024}}

Test_4)
dataChangeFilterTrigger = StatusValue
dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue = 1
2024-07-04 06:40:24,583 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488242348177, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:24 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488242348177, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:24 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:25,584 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.05}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488252284656, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:25 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488252284656, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:25 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:26,584 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488257747604, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:25 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488257747604, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:25 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:27,586 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488273022197, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:27 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488273022197, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:27 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:28,584 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.925}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488282885735, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:28 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488282885735, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:28 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:29,583 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488292682931, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:29 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488292682931, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:29 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:30,588 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.8}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488302517455, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:30 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488302517455, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:30 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:31,587 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.9666667}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488312376079, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:31 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488312376079, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:31 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:32,588 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488322267329, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:32 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488322267329, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:32 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:33,586 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488327669740, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:32 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488327669740, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:32 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 06:40:34,581 milo-shared-thread-pool-0 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.0}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488342986708, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:34 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645488342986708, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 06:40:34 UTC 2024}}

Test_5)
dataChangeFilterTrigger = StatusValue
dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue = 10
2024-07-04 09:00:48,048 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572479092312, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:47 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572479092312, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:47 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 09:00:49,049 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572490049997, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:49 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572490049997, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:49 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 09:00:50,056 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.925}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572499931469, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:49 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572499931469, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:49 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 09:00:51,056 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=2.925}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572509718650, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:50 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572509718650, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:50 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 09:00:52,057 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572519602261, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:51 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572519602261, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:51 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 09:00:53,053 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.2}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572525013237, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:52 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572525013237, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:52 UTC 2024}}
2024-07-04 09:00:54,056 milo-shared-thread-pool-1 INFO - [routeDeadband] - **** DataValue{value=Variant{value=3.1333334}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572539303064, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:53 UTC 2024}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=133645572539303064, javaDate=Thu Jul 04 09:00:53 UTC 2024}}

In the tests performed the behavior is always the same. if you look the sequence data values DataValue{value=Variant{value=xx} of each test in several cases I wouldn't have to receive any values, because the deadband value wasn't overcome.
if I try to set the same deadband value like the Test_4 with Prosys OPC UA Client I have got the right behavior


ISSUE SOLVED
Created UInteger Bean instance set to 1 value in Bean Configuration, see the following:
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    
    @Bean("DeadbandParamater")
    public UInteger deadbandParamater() {
        return UInteger.valueOf(1);
    }

} 

After that the right configuration of OPC UA milo client
from("milo-client:opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?
keyStoreUrl=file:C:\\Temp\\application\\certificate\\clientkeystore.jks
&keyPassword=123456
&keyStorePassword=123456
&applicationUri=urn:8409:test:camelopcua
&applicationName=camelopcua&node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA)
&dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue=0.2
&dataChangeFilterTrigger=StatusValue
&dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=#bean:DeadbandParamater
&monitorFilterType=dataChangeFilter
&samplingInterval=1000").log("**** ${body}").routeId("routeDeadband");

ref bean by using query parameter syntax
dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=#bean:DeadbandParamater

link to DataChangeFilter
Test performed:


Can you get a Wireshark capture of the entire session?
It's possible that the client isn't creating the MonitoredItems with the correct settings, and it's also possible that the server is simply ignoring the deadband, in which case there's nothing you can do but complain to that server vendor.
edit:
It looks like you are not setting the dataChangeFilterDeadbandType configuration value. See https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.22.x/components/camel-milo/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/milo/client/MonitorFilterConfiguration.java

look the post with the screenshot, if I try with Prosys OPC UA Client the deadband value works fine. Consider that both services (OPC UA Server and Client) are in the same machine. Can Wireshark works when the both services are in the same machine ?  Can I have alternative to verify what you told me ?

Wireshark does work when both software is on the same machine. I'm not familiar enough with either client or server software to suggest an alternative method. Wireshark provides an objective view of what is happening.

See my recent edit.

I have added the test answering to my question. Setting dataChangeFilterDeadbandType value but I've got the TypeConversionException error.

Starting from documentation dataChangeFilterDeadbandType by default is zero.

I have tried to set dataChangeFilterDeadbandType to 0 or 1 value and other values but I've got the same error.
Tests performed:
Test_6
INPUT QUERY PARAMETERS:
dataChangeFilterTrigger = StatusValue

dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue = 10

dataChangeFilterDeadbandType = 0

RESULT
Main cause:
Caused by: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger with value 0 due to org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger] for value [0]

Complete stacktrace:
2024-07-05 08:37:36,335 main INFO - [c.b.f.j.QuartzRoutingJobService] - START OPCUA route config
2024-07-05 08:37:36,366 main INFO - [c.b.f.j.QuartzRoutingJobService] - END Scanning routes

2024-07-05 08:37:36,642 main INFO - [o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] - Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2024-07-05 08:37:36,658 main INFO - [o.a.c.c.StandardService] - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-07-05 08:37:36,658 main INFO - [o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger] -

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-05 08:37:36,689 main ERROR - [o.s.b.SpringApplication] - Application run failed
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route routeDeadband: Route(routeDeadband)[From[milo-client:opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: milo-client://opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?applicationName=camelopcua&applicationUri=urn%3A8409%3Atest%3Acamelopcua&dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=0&dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue=10&dataChangeFilterTrigger=StatusValue&keyPassword=xxxxxx&keyStorePassword=xxxxxx&keyStoreUrl=xxxxxx&node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA) due to: Error binding property (dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=0) with name: dataChangeFilterDeadbandType on bean: milo-client://opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?applicationName=camelopcua&applicationUri=urn%3A8409%3Atest%3Acamelopcua&dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=0&dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue=10&dataChangeFilterTrigger=StatusValue&keyPassword=xxxxxx&keyStorePassword=xxxxxx&keyStoreUrl=xxxxxx&node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2%20SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA) with value: 0
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:85) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelReifierFactory.createRoute(DefaultModelReifierFactory.java:49) ~[camel-core-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:728) ~[camel-core-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:594) ~[camel-core-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2385) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:78) ~[camel-api-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2021) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:105) ~[camel-api-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2040) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:212) ~[camel-core-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119) ~[camel-spring-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151) ~[camel-spring-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:384) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:981) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at com.xx.fileservice.FileserviceApplication.main(FileserviceApplication.java:24) [main/:?]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: milo-client://opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?applicationName=camelopcua&applicationUri=urn%3A8409%3Atest%3Acamelopcua&dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=0&dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue=10&dataChangeFilterTrigger=StatusValue&keyPassword=xxxxxx&keyStorePassword=xxxxxx&keyStoreUrl=xxxxxx&node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2 SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA) due to: Error binding property (dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=0) with name: dataChangeFilterDeadbandType on bean: milo-client://opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?applicationName=camelopcua&applicationUri=urn%3A8409%3Atest%3Acamelopcua&dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=0&dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue=10&dataChangeFilterTrigger=StatusValue&keyPassword=xxxxxx&keyStorePassword=xxxxxx&keyStoreUrl=xxxxxx&node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2%20SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA) with value: 0
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:830) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:730) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:61) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:195) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:99) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:79) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.PropertyBindingException: Error binding property (dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=0) with name: dataChangeFilterDeadbandType on bean: milo-client://opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49310?applicationName=camelopcua&applicationUri=urn%3A8409%3Atest%3Acamelopcua&dataChangeFilterDeadbandType=0&dataChangeFilterDeadbandValue=10&dataChangeFilterTrigger=StatusValue&keyPassword=xxxxxx&keyStorePassword=xxxxxx&keyStoreUrl=xxxxxx&node=RAW(ns=2;s=Channel2%20SIMUL.SIM_1.BNAp1.18VGG1_1XA) with value: 0
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.setSimplePropertyViaConfigurer(PropertyBindingSupport.java:807) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doSetPropertyValue(PropertyBindingSupport.java:564) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doBuildPropertyOgnlPath(PropertyBindingSupport.java:420) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doBindProperties(PropertyBindingSupport.java:300) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport$Builder.bind(PropertyBindingSupport.java:1941) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.setProperties(DefaultEndpoint.java:424) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.configureProperties(DefaultEndpoint.java:396) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:421) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientComponent.createEndpoint(MiloClientComponent.java:45) ~[camel-milo-3.22.2.jar:3.22.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:170) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:796) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:730) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:61) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:195) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:99) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:79) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger with value 0 due to org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger] for value [0]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringTypeConverter.convertTo(SpringTypeConverter.java:73) ~[camel-spring-boot-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvert(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:466) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.tryFallback(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:435) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:384) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertToAndStat(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:272) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:196) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:183) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.component.PropertyConfigurerSupport.property(PropertyConfigurerSupport.java:95) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientEndpointConfigurer.configure(MiloClientEndpointConfigurer.java:37) ~[camel-milo-3.22.2.jar:3.22.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.setSimplePropertyViaConfigurer(PropertyBindingSupport.java:805) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doSetPropertyValue(PropertyBindingSupport.java:564) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doBuildPropertyOgnlPath(PropertyBindingSupport.java:420) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doBindProperties(PropertyBindingSupport.java:300) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport$Builder.bind(PropertyBindingSupport.java:1941) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.setProperties(DefaultEndpoint.java:424) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.configureProperties(DefaultEndpoint.java:396) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:421) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientComponent.createEndpoint(MiloClientComponent.java:45) ~[camel-milo-3.22.2.jar:3.22.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:170) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:796) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:730) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:61) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:195) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:99) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:79) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger] for value [0]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:182) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringTypeConverter.convertTo(SpringTypeConverter.java:62) ~[camel-spring-boot-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvert(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:466) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.tryFallback(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:435) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:384) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertToAndStat(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:272) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:196) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:183) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.component.PropertyConfigurerSupport.property(PropertyConfigurerSupport.java:95) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientEndpointConfigurer.configure(MiloClientEndpointConfigurer.java:37) ~[camel-milo-3.22.2.jar:3.22.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.setSimplePropertyViaConfigurer(PropertyBindingSupport.java:805) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doSetPropertyValue(PropertyBindingSupport.java:564) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doBuildPropertyOgnlPath(PropertyBindingSupport.java:420) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doBindProperties(PropertyBindingSupport.java:300) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport$Builder.bind(PropertyBindingSupport.java:1941) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.setProperties(DefaultEndpoint.java:424) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.configureProperties(DefaultEndpoint.java:396) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:421) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientComponent.createEndpoint(MiloClientComponent.java:45) ~[camel-milo-3.22.2.jar:3.22.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:170) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:796) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:730) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:61) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:195) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:99) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:79) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert String [0] to target class [org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.UInteger]
        at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:222) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:64) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:50) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:409) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:182) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringTypeConverter.convertTo(SpringTypeConverter.java:62) ~[camel-spring-boot-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvert(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:466) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.tryFallback(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:435) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:384) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertToAndStat(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:272) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:196) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.CoreTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(CoreTypeConverterRegistry.java:183) ~[camel-base-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.component.PropertyConfigurerSupport.property(PropertyConfigurerSupport.java:95) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientEndpointConfigurer.configure(MiloClientEndpointConfigurer.java:37) ~[camel-milo-3.22.2.jar:3.22.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.setSimplePropertyViaConfigurer(PropertyBindingSupport.java:805) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doSetPropertyValue(PropertyBindingSupport.java:564) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doBuildPropertyOgnlPath(PropertyBindingSupport.java:420) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport.doBindProperties(PropertyBindingSupport.java:300) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.PropertyBindingSupport$Builder.bind(PropertyBindingSupport.java:1941) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.setProperties(DefaultEndpoint.java:424) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.configureProperties(DefaultEndpoint.java:396) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:421) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientComponent.createEndpoint(MiloClientComponent.java:45) ~[camel-milo-3.22.2.jar:3.22.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:170) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:796) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:730) ~[camel-base-engine-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:61) ~[camel-support-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:195) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:99) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:79) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.4.2.jar:4.4.2]
        ... 25 more

> Task :bootRun FAILED

Am I wrong to set the format value ?

I think now you'll need help from somebody familiar with the camel-milo project.

@KevinHerron issue solved.
